# Why is-a-role-of is one of the inheritance mistakes?

Tags: oop, inheritance, composition

The illustration below is taken from my lecture slide. I've use both composition and inheritance to code a `Student - Person` class, I think both of them pretty reasonable.

(I know if One person can have many positions -  1:n , then inheritance doesn't work though, so I'm only taking about 1 person : 2 position relationship).

[image]

The code using Inheritance:

```
class Person
    attr_accessor :name, :gender, :height, :weight
    def initialize(name, gender, height, weight)
        @name = name
        @gender = gender
        @height = height
        @weight = weight
    end
    def cry
        "woooo"
    end
end


class Student < Person
    attr_accessor :student_id
    def initialize(name, gender, height, weight, student_id)
        super(name, gender, height, weight)
        @student_id = student_id
    end
    def study
        "Student #{name} with #{student_id} is studying now"
    end
end

s = Student.new("Lin", "Male", 173, 75, 666777)
puts s.cry()
puts s.study
```

Code using Composition:

```
class Person
    attr_accessor :name, :gender, :height, :weight, :position
    def initialize(name, gender, height, weight, position = nil)
        @name = name
        @gender = gender
        @height = height
        @weight = weight
        @position = position
    end
    def cry
        "woooo"
    end
end


class Student
    attr_accessor :student_id
    def initialize(student_id)

        @student_id = student_id
    end
    def study
        "#{student_id} is studying now"
    end
end
s = Student.new(666777)
p = Person.new("Lin", "Male", 173, 75, s)
puts p.cry()
puts p.position.study
```

And I found the code using composition has one bad side, I can't make `student` call he's name. I mean I can't make the study() method return something like the inheritance code does:

```
"Student #{name} with #{student_id} is studying now"
```

Comment: What if someone is both a Postgrad and Tutor? How is that person represented as an object?

Comment: @Patashu You are 100% right. But in the second paragraph, I declare that I'm only taking about 1:1 in this case,